# SQL Server partitioning monthly data by weeks and calculating weekly weighted average based on month days of that week belong to

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
Month          Value
2012-08-01      0.345
2012-09-01      0.543
2012-10-01      0.321
2012-11-01      0.234
2012-12-01      0.234
```

User inputs week range from '2012-09-29' to '2012-10-13'
Output should show results for all weeks in requested range and average values for each week with the following logic:
 - if all weekdays are entirely in one month, just use monthly value for that month
 - if weekdays are spread out over two months, calculate weekly value as average between those two months giving preference to the month that contains the most days of that week.

If someone can give me an idea how to do something like this in T-SQL that would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [last query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5393/0) is the example.  The Calendar table is built on-request, but every database can do with a persisted Calendar table, on which you would filter the date range instead.

```
declare @tbl table (
  Month datetime,
  Value decimal(10,3));
insert @tbl select
'2012-08-01',      0.345 union all select
'2012-09-01',      0.543 union all select
'2012-10-01',      0.321 union all select
'2012-11-01',      0.234 union all select
'2012-12-01',      0.234;

declare @start datetime, @end datetime;
select @start = '2012-09-29', @end ='2012-10-13';

;with Calendar(TheDate,StartOfWeek,StartOfMonth) as(
  select @start, @start+1-Datepart(dw,@start), @start-Day(@start)+1
  union all
  select TheDate+1, TheDate+1+1-Datepart(dw,TheDate+1),
         TheDate+1-Day(TheDate+1)+1
  from Calendar
  where TheDate < @end
)
select case when @start > v.StartOfWeek
            then @start else v.StartOfWeek end RangeStart,
       case when @end < v.StartOfWeek+6
            then @end else v.StartOfWeek+6 end RangeEnd,
       cast(avg(m.value) as decimal(10,3)) [Average]
from Calendar v
join @tbl m on v.StartOfMonth = m.Month
group by v.StartOfWeek;
```

Output

```
RANGESTART          RANGEEND            Average
September, 29 2012  September, 29 2012  0.543
September, 30 2012  October, 06 2012    0.353
October, 07 2012    October, 13 2012    0.321
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query would be something like this.  The idea is find the first day of the next month **DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, Month) + 1, 0**.  Calculate the number of days, and then you can get the monthly total, and calculate the average based on the difference between the first day of the current month and next month.  (SQL syntax may need some clean up).

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare  @enddate datetime

set @startdate = '2012-09-05'
set @enddate ='2012-10-13'

 Select Monthtotal/DateDiff(d,Month,NextMonth)
    FROM
        (Select 
         Month, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, Month) + 1, 0) NextMonth, 
         DateDiff(d,Month, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, Month) + 1, 0) * Value as Monthtotal
        FROM  DatesTable
        WHERE 
            @startdate >= Month and 
            @enddate <= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, Month) + 1, 0))
```